# When this $f(x)=\frac{\log x}{x}$ decreasing and when is it increasing

Tags: functional-analysis, logarithms

> When this$f(x)=\frac{\log x}{x}$ decreasing and when is it increasing?

Usually in graph increasing function identified by $f'(x)>0$ and vice versa for decreasing. In this case, however, after I get $f'(x) =\frac{ 1 - \log x}{x^2}$ i am confused in deciding when is it increasing or decreasing.

Comment: By $\log x$, do you mean $\log_{10} x$ or $\log_e x$?

Comment: The only important thing is the sign of $f'(x)$. Since the denominator is alway positive on the domain of $f$, you only need to determine when is $1-\log x>0$ and when this is negative, which should be straightforward given the monotonicity of $\log x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f'(x) >0$ if $x <e$ and $f'(x) <0$ if $x >e$. So $f$ is increasing in $(0,e)$ and decreasing in $(e,\infty)$.

Answer (score 1):

The derivative with respect o $x$ of the above function is
$$
f'(x) = x^{-2} \left( 1-\ln (x) \right) \, .
$$

Thus for $x<e$ the function is increasing and for $x>e$ it is decreasing.